# How to upload image with Alamofire from camera roll

Tags: swift, nsurl, alamofire

I am having trouble uploading image with Alamofire. Problem is very simple - I do not know how get fileURL(NSURL) for a selected image.
Here is simple code from Alamofire GitHub:

```
Alamofire.upload(
                    .POST,
                    "myCustomServerURL",
                    multipartFormData: { multipartFormData in
                        multipartFormData.appendBodyPart(data: "_formname".dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding, allowLossyConversion: false)!, name :"default")
                            //How to get fireURL?
                            multipartFormData.appendBodyPart(fileURL: imageURL, name: "unicorn")
                        },
                        encodingCompletion: { encodingResult in
                            switch encodingResult {
                            case .Success(let upload, _, _):
                                upload.responseJSON { response in
                                    debugPrint(response)
                                }
                            case .Failure(let encodingError):
                                print(encodingError)
                            }
                        }
                    )
```

What is the usual way to get NSURL for local files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You get the `UIImage` instance from the picker. Take the image and write it to disk als jpg ([UIImageJPEGRepresentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIKitFunctionReference/index.html#//apple_ref/c/func/UIImageJPEGRepresentation)) or png ([UIImagePNGRepresentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIKitFunctionReference/index.html#//apple_ref/c/func/UIImagePNGRepresentation)) and use the file URL for the store image.

Comment: Thanks, but the hard part for me is how to get URL from file? Using example from HackingWithSwift I am able to save image like this: `let imageName = NSUUID().UUIDString
        let imagePath = getDocumentsDirectory().stringByAppendingPathComponent(imageName)
        
        if let jpegData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(newImage, 80) {
            jpegData.writeToFile(imagePath, atomically: true)
        }`
But the hard part for me is to get URL. Could give me an example how to get URL?

Comment: When you have the file path, you can get the URL with the `NSURL` class method `fileURLWithPath`.

Comment: Like this: `let url:NSURL = NSURL.fileURLWithPath(imagePath)`? Because app still fails to upload image to server

Comment: Nevermind, you were absolutely right. I made typo mistake in my parameters that I have to send to server, thus app was getting errors.
Thanks very much!